# Passing strings in c# to a static statement

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create a SQL database in c# by having my program connect to the server. I am having a problem with creating a login screen. The problem is in order to create a login screen. I am trying to pass 2 strings to the connection class and am unable to do so since the statement is static?

```
public class sqlconnect
{
    public String us;
    public String pas;

    public SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=" + (us) + ";" +
                                           "password=" + (pas) + ";server=PANDORA;" +
                                           "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                           "database=NHS; " +
                                           "connection timeout=30");
}
```

---

```
ERROR - A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property
```

If I try and make "us" or "pas" static I am unable to pass information from my main class to this one. I would be grateful if someone could point out what I'm doing wrong as I am not an expert at C# I must admit. Thank you.

Comment: You need to run that code in a method after assigning username/password (most likely this is what you intended to do). EDIT: Boatload of other issues (username/password as clear text, input validation, public fields) but that's outside the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// property
public SqlConnection myConnection { get; set; }

// method
public SqlConnection GetSqlConnection()
{
     if (myConnection == null) 
       myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=" + us + ";" +
                                       "password=" + pas + ";server=PANDORA;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=NHS; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");

     return myConnection;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can't use variables within a field initializer.  A good option here would be to make `myConnection` a property or (better yet, in this case) a method:

```
public SqlConnection CreateConnection()
{
     return new SqlConnection("user id=" + us + ";" +
                                       "password=" + pas + ";server=PANDORA;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=NHS; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");
}
```

This allows you to use your other variables (state) in order to create the value you want.

I would also recommend changing your string values to properties, having a constructor to initialize them property, and using better names.  Another alternative would be to have the username and password be parameters to the method, ie:

```
public SqlConnection CreateConnection(string username, string password)
{
     return new SqlConnection("user id=" + username + ";" +
                                       "password=" + password + ";server=PANDORA;" +
                                       "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                       "database=NHS; " +
                                       "connection timeout=30");
}
```

This would elimniate the need to store these within your class as state (unless they're used by other routines, as well).

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that, sorry!

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Just edited to include that suggestion, though ;)  I think its another good option.

Comment: I did think about something like that however how would I then go about opening the connection from the main class? as my main class calls the method but it can't open the connection?

Comment: @Marshal that's likely another issue altogether. Are you doubly-sure that the information you're inputting and the method you're connecting are correct?